# Linkedserver to PostgreSQL, truncation error

Tags: linked-server

I have a truncation error when I try to insert a ntext column to a text column on PostgreSQL side.
The tables are:

MSSQL:

```
Create Table TestMSTable(
ms_id bigint  identity,
    name ntext,
    primary key (ms_id)
)
```

PostgreSQL:

```
Create Table TestPGTable(
pg_id BIGSERIAL,
    name text,
    primary key (pg_id)
)
```

And when I try to insert it:

```
INSERT INTO [POSTGRESQL].[TestDB].[public].[testpgtable](Name) SELECT name FROM TestMSTable;
```

I get an error:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 17
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

In theory both column datatypes are unlimited. I also tried to set @@TEXTSITE to -1 , still same error.
Any suggestion how to avoid those truncations?